# Ar multiple joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I have the following models:

```
class Distributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Producer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :favorite
  belongs_to :producer
  belongs_to :distributor
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
end
```

I would like to build a AR expression is analog of sql query:

```
select *
from `favorites`
inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `favorites`.`product_id`
inner join `producers` on `producers`.`id` = `products`.`producer_id`
inner join `distributors` on `distributors`.`id` = `products`.`distributor_id`
where `favorites`.`user_id` = 1
```

Comment: please specify the user model relation in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested set of `joins` methods like this:

```
Favorite.joins(:product => [:producer , :distributor]).where("favorites.user_id = 1")
```

Note that i am using the `=>` notation, but you can use the ruby 1.9+ one too.

Comment: Got an error **ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'products' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?**

Comment: Try `:product` then. It is a `belongs_to` relationship.

Comment: Got an another error **ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'producers' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?**

Comment: The thing is: when you have a `belongs_to` relationship, you use the singular name on the `joins` method. When you have a `has_many` you use the plural form.

Comment: Its clear for me. But there's no relation between Producer and Distributor models. Only between Product -> Producer and Product -> Distributor. Your suggestion is not suitable for my case.